# How to disable photo library and icloud selection on file input in ipad

Tags: jquery, html

Just wandering, will it be possible to disable photo library and icloud selection on file input in ipad with jquery or html?

I have the following html code use to attached file when button been clicked:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadBtn" class="uploadBtn">
```

At the moment, if I run the code in ipad, when attached button been clicked, it will pop up a dialog and allows the user to either take a photo, select from photo library or from the icould. Anyway I can disable the photo library and icloud selection on file input in ipad with jquery ot html?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to force the user to take a photo? Or you would allow other applications, just not photo library and icloud?

Comment: @Milk To force it to take a photo if the page is open in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this through an `input` button.

Your alternative is to capture an image via the camera on the web page with something like the below and then push the image to your server.

**HTML**

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}

// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
});
```

Source: https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera